# How to update Customization of Fixture in AutoFixture

Tags: unit-testing, autofixture

In the `Testbase` class it customizes `MyClass` like this

```
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.Without(r => r.Foo));
```

and in the sub-class of `Testbase` it has

```
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.Without(r => r.Bar));
```

The problem is I want to add more customization into `MyClass` creating but seems the last wins/overrides the first so it still sets `MyClass.Foo`.
So how can I update customization instead override it?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but as far as I know you'll have to write your own fixture to pass into the ICustomization's Customize method.

Here's an example that I made: https://github.com/LethargicDeveloper/Lift.AutoFixture

I created an extension method called "Compose()" takes an ICustomization. It injects a special fixture into the customization classes that you've defined and combines all the customization before adding them to your original fixture's Customization collection.

Below is a snippet from the code that does most of the work.
A Fixture has a Customization collection that holds all the customizations that will get applied. The Customization collection is a List< ISpecimenBuilder > and as far as I know there's no easy way to know what types each builder will create. So in my new fixture I hold on to the type information in a Dictionary and wait until you call BuildFixture before the actual customizations are added to the Customization list.

The key is in the Customize< T > method. That's the method on the fixture that you're calling to create your customization, so we override it. Every time it's called the current customization is pulled out of the Builders list for the given type and composed with the new customization before being set back in the Builders list.

```
internal class ComposableCustomizationBuilder : IFixture
{
    private readonly IFixture fixture;

    public ComposableCustomizationBuilder(IFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
        this.Builders = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    // most of the IFixture methods have been removed for brevity since they just return the this.fixture implementation.

    internal Dictionary<Type, object> Builders { get; }

    public IFixture Customize(ICustomization customization)
    {
        customization.Customize(this);
        return this;
    }

    public void Customize<T>(Func<ICustomizationComposer<T>, ISpecimenBuilder> composerTransformation)
    {
        if (!this.Builders.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object builder))
        {
            var specimenBuilder = composerTransformation(SpecimenBuilderNodeFactory.CreateComposer<T>().WithAutoProperties(true));
            this.Builders.Add(typeof(T), new NodeComposer<T>(specimenBuilder));
            return;
        }

        this.Builders[typeof(T)] = composerTransformation(builder as ICustomizationComposer<T>);
    }

    internal IFixture BuildFixture()
    {
        if (this.fixture is ComposableCustomizationBuilder)
        {
            return this;
        }

        foreach (var builder in this.Builders)
        {
            var specimenBuilder = builder.Value as ISpecimenBuilder;
            this.fixture.Customizations.Add(specimenBuilder);
        }

        return this.fixture;
    }
}
```

Using your example you could write it like this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
  .Compose<NoBar>()
  .Compose<NoFoo>()
  .Compose();

var result = fixture.Create<MyClass>();

// All the properties should be set as normal by autofixture except for both Foo and Bar which should be omitted.

public class NoBar : ICustomization
{
   public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
   {
      fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.Without(r => r.Bar));
   }
}

public class NoFoo : ICustomization
{
   public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
   {
      fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.Without(r => r.Foo));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot do that. The `Customize<>` API always appends a new customization, so the previous one is overridden - it's by design.

As a possible workaround, you might use a bit different syntax to omit individual properties:

```cs
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new Omitter(
        new EqualRequestSpecification(
            typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Foo)))));
```

This way you can append customizations and extend the exceptions list later:

```cs
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new Omitter(
        new EqualRequestSpecification(
            typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Bar)))));
```

Be aware that approach affects the whole class hierarchy if you have inheritance. So if you omit `BaseClass.Foo`, it will also omit the `Foo` property in each child class.